# Sprite Atlases and How to Use Them

Tags: unity-game-engine

Basically, I'm trying to lower the build size by using atlases.

I have various sprites, I packed them up with atlases and compressed them. Everything is clear up to this point

However, I don't see a way to use sprites in the atlases. When I create a new UI image what do I suppose to drag and drop to the source image field?

**----EDIT---**

I read this. https://forum.unity.com/threads/sprite-atlas-adding-on-build-size.608143/ It seems that this procedure is all automated.

https://blog.yarsalabs.com/game-optimization-using-unity-sprite-atlas/ In here it says "After the sprite atlas creation is done, we don't have to worry about missing image references in our Unity project because Unity's sprite atlas replaces all the old images with the currently packed atlas images."

However, all of my sprites are still **included in the build.**

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for the new information.

Comment: Do you have any sprites in your resources folder?

Comment: an atlas is not magically reducing your size .. in worst case even increases in size if all your sprites together do not fit exactly within a rectangular pixels space and leave blank unused holes!

Answer (score 0):

Using an atlas is not aimed at reducing build size. In fact, more atlases increase build size.

Atlas aims to be an optimization that reduces the draw calls of one scene.

After dragging and dropping each source file into Objects for Packing of Atlas, A simple usage is as follows.

```
img.sprite = atlas.GetSprite(name);
```

'name' is the name(string) of the resource in the Project folder.

**----After reading the edits-----**

Thanks for letting me know what I was doing wrong.
I'd appreciate if someone could point me to what the sprite resource still includes.

Comment: after reimporting the assets build size reduced a lot

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the issue.

Just Reimport All :/